# What is the highest achievable height by flying?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am asking about the maximum height that can be reached by flying. I would like to try it for myself, but I am scared that it would crush my devices.
Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Normally it would be 256 blocks from bottom to top, but I'm not sure if thats the case for the bedrock edition... What device do you got ? :)

Comment: Sorry I an not asking the highest possible height for building blocks. The height that I can achieve by flying or using commands

Comment: Edit your question again to include flying or by commands specifically. At first glance, it looks like you're asking for the maximum build limit.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum height the player can reach by flying is Y=2<sup>52</sup> (or 4.50x10<sup>15</sup>). If the player managed to climb up further, at Y=2<sup>55</sup> (or 3.60x10<sup>16</sup>) the player loses the ability to fall.

As for commands, the maximum number that a player can teleport to is Y=4096.

---

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Altitude), [Wiki archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20191011084300/https://minecraft.wiki/w/Altitude)

Comment: It doesn't show the highest achievable height by flying in minecraft bedrock edition.

Comment: You're right, but I think everything the wiki states are applicable to all versions of the game unless stated otherwise. There are some lines that make me think this way: "In the New **Nintendo 3DS Edition**,"... and "In **Bedrock Edition**, the player"...